# Problem zone file configuration bind9

Tags: configuration, bind, dns-zone

this is my configuration file zone

> > ```
> > $TTL 604800
> > @  IN      SOA     SH.globaltic.tk.      root.globaltic.tk. (
> >                                          2011052501 ;serial
> >                                          604800     ; Refresh
> >                                          86400      ; Retry
> >                                          2419200    ; Expire
> >                                          604800     ; Negative Cache TTL )
> >
> > @           IN      NS      SH.globaltic.tk.
> > @           IN      NS      mail.globaltic.tk.
> > @           IN      MX  10  mail.globaltic.tk.
> > SH          IN      A       192.168.1.1
> > mail        IN      A       192.168.1.2
> > ```

when I did a test:

> > ```
> > root@SH:/etc/bind#named-checkzone globaltic.tk db.globaltic.tk
> > dns_rdata_fromtext: db.globaltic.tk:7: near '@': extra input text
> > zone globaltic.tk/IN: loading from master file db.globaltic.tk failed: extra input     >>     text
> > zone globaltic.tk/IN: not loaded due to errors.
> > ```

*I erased each time an "@​​" I made ​​a change each time it is the same problem.*
*an answer?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the closing bracket right behind the 604800, like this:

```
604800 )    ; Negative Cache TTL
```

and it will work.

The way you have written your zone file, the closing bracket is part of the comment, and therefore the parser cannot see it as part of the SOA declaration. When you move it to before the comment starts, the parser can see it.

Comment: extra plus one if you explain WHY.

Comment: Is that better ?

Comment: yes problem is resolved ;-)

Comment: @wolfgangz Yes, thanks! (sorry to be picky, but even though it was "obvious" to some folks, sometimes a little thing like that is difficult to notice.

Comment: @Jed, you are quite right. And this site is about educating people, not just fixing their problems.